# Query where table.column not in replace altered column of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure the answer is staring right at me, but I can't figure it out. I've 2 tables with the same number, in one table only with numbers, in the other with dashes randomly strewn throughout (yes, garbage in). I'm trying to query one where the value ignoring the dashes is not in another table. I can get it to work for IN but it is not working for NOT IN. What am I doing wrong here?

This query, the same as below but with IN instead of NOT IN, works:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a 
WHERE reference_number IN (SELECT replace(reference_number_messy,'-','') 
                          FROM table_b)
```

This query, the same as the one above but with NOT IN instead of IN, I would think would return all in table_a not in the above query, but it is not. Instead it returns no results:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a 
WHERE reference_number NOT IN (SELECT replace(reference_number_messy,'-','') 
                               FROM table_b)
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get this second "NOT IN" query to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have `NULL` values in subquery. You could avoid it using `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a
WHERE reference_number NOT IN (
                  SELECT COALESCE(replace(reference_number_messy,'-','') ,'')
                  FROM table_b);
```

or filtering it out:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a
WHERE reference_number NOT IN (
                  SELECT replace(reference_number_messy,'-','')
                  FROM table_b
                  WHERE reference_number_messy IS NOT NULL);
```

---

Explanation:

```
x IN (y, z)      <=> x = y OR x = z
x NOT IN (y,z)   <=> x != y AND x != z
```

Comparing anything to `NULL` will yield `UNKNOWN` (not true). So you get no rows.

Comment: There were NULL values in table_b. However, neither of these solutions work. They both return a similar error. The second (filtering) solution returns the following error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-listings
WHERE folio NOT IN 
( 
    SELECT replace(`reference_number_messy`,'-','')
        ' at line 1

Comment: `WHERE folio NOT IN ( SELECT replace(reference_number_messy,'-','')` so you posted  simplified query and now you claim that it has syntax error. Sorry but I cannot help you without your full and actual query.

Comment: SELECT * FROM o_m-m WHERE folio NOT IN ( SELECT replace(FNumber,'-','') FROM wrldb WHERE FNumber IS NOT NULL);

Comment: I realized as I pasted it in that the problem is the dash in the o_m-m table name. Changed this. Now works.  Thank you!